# SharePoint 2019 on-prem modern search result inconsistencies

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, modern-experience, sharepoint-search, modern-pages

I'm trying to understand the modern search experience with SharePoint 2019 on-prem. There appears to be some inconsistency in the results that are presenting the new modern search box "immediate" results, I think is what it's referred to as. In this example. I have an OOTB Modern Communication site, with a News article (My IT site is now live), and a modern page (Request a service).

As you can see in the first screenshot, on the SharePoint homepage, both results are displayed immediately when a user places the cursor in the search box, exactly what I want.

[image: SharePoint homepage search results]

The second screenshot is the search box on the My IT Communication site. You can see that the search results that appear in the modern search box are missing the "Request a service" page. And actually doesn't list any files at all.

[image: My IT Communication site search box immediate results]

The third screenshot is to demonstrate that the page is actually indexed, and gets displayed on the search results screen:

[image: My IT Communication site search results]

Am I missing something here? Shouldn't the "Request a service" page be getting displayed in the immediate search box results? Is there some file type restriction on this modern search box? And if so is it configurable? I've spent plenty of time googling this and reading through the "documentation", but I haven't found much in the way of substance that will help me understand how this modern search box works, and if at all it can be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you click "More results" when you type the page name in the "Search this site" search box in communication site?

Per my test, when I enter the search page, the result appear in the page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The experience is exactly the same on the search results page. The "Request a service" page (and any pages that aren't news) don't display in the immediate search results.

Out of curiosity, your screenshot looks like SharePoint online. This issue is only apparent in on-prem, at least in my experience.